# IN statement jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling a bit with jQuery/JavaScript..
How can I do this more simple?

```
if ($(".Name").text() == "One" ||
    $(".Name").text() == "Bear" ||
    $(".Name").text() == "Two" ||
    $(".Name").text() == "Bla" ||
    $(".Name").text() == "Red")

  doFunction();

}
```

Is there a some kind of "IN" statement in jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You Can try [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) method:

```
if( $.inArray( $(".Name").text(), [ 'One', 'Bear', 'Two', 'Bla', 'Red' ] ) !== -1 ) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all these values into array and use `IndexOf'
for example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
```

a will get value bigger than zero if Apple is exists inside fruits otherwise a will get the value `-1`

For more info, see the next [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

If you want do it through JQuery in simpler way, use [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has ways of doing it, but you can make using *vanilla* [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (['One', 'Bear', 'Two', 'Bla', 'Red'].indexOf($(".Name").text()) !== -1) {
    // found
}
```

---

If [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is the operator you really want to use, then let's look up what it does

> The `in` operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

So, you could use `in` by checking against an *Object* which has *keys* of the possible matches you want

```
if ($(".Name").text() in {'One': 1, 'Bear': 1, 'Two': 1, 'Bla': 1, 'Red': 1}) {
    // found
}
```

Please note that this may have some false positives, e.g. `'toString' in {}; // true`

Comment: As Royi points out, IE doesn't support `.indexOf` until version 9. However, you could include the polyfill found on the _MDN_ page if you need to consider IE 7, 8

Answer (score 1):

You can use array here

create array like

```
var myarray = ['One', 'Bear', 'Two', 'Bla', 'Red'];
```

and use below jquery

```
if($.inArray($(".Name").text(), myarray)!=-1) {
    console.log("is in array");
}
```

Comment: It will always print `"is in array"`.

Comment: @dfsq, thanks for pointing out the error. I have added the `!=-1` in if condition :). Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do . like this

```
var arr=["One","Bear","Two","Bla","Red"];
var urname=$(".Name").text();
if(jQuery.inArray( urname, arr ) != -1){
    alert("yes");
}else{
alert("no");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/eyhzuuxc/)